# jQuery validation: apply rule to input only if form id contains text

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form looking like this

```
<form id="new_user" action="users">
  <input  id="user_email" class="string email required span5 valid" type="text"    
  value="nicolas@demoreau.be" size="80" placeholder="user@domain.com" name="user[email]">
</form>
```

If I want to update my user, the form id becomes "edit_user". I want to add a rule on my user_email only if the form id contains "new". I tried to do it this way:

```
$("form[id*=new][data-validate=true]").find("#user_email").rules("add", {
  remote: {
    url: "check_email",
    type: "post"
  },
  messages: {
    remote: "There is already a user with this email address!"
  }
});
```

But this creates an error when I use the edit form: "element is undefined", which is normal as it can't find a user_email anywhere.

What would be the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

try only this,

```
$("#user_email").rules("add", {
         remote: {
             url: "check_email",
             type: "post"
         },
         messages: {
             remote: "There is already a user with this email address!"
         }
        });
    });
```

Comment: This works also if my form has "edit" in its id which is what I'm trying to avoid: I want to add this rule ONLY if the form has "new" in its id. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the form and element you want exist before creating the rule.

```
if ($("form[id*=new][data-validate=true]").find("#user_email").length > 0){
    $('#user_email').rules("add", {
      remote: {
        url: "check_email",
        type: "post"
      },
      messages: {
        remote: "There is already a user with this email address!"
      }
    });
}
```